# Why do we need variable (linear) voltage regulators when fixed regulators give the required voltages?

Tags: voltage-regulator

Digital ICs would need voltage rails 5.0V, 3.3V, 2.5V, 1.8V and 1.2V. There are fixed voltage regulators that can provide all of them. Where are the variable voltage regulators required and used then?

Comment: There are some reasons: Utilize voltage level according battery (-ies) effective range. Changing the supply voltage during operation according situation. Combination with fixed regulator where precise difference between them is needed. Some loads need a special level.

Comment: The situation you pose is modern and wasn't always the case. For example, +5 and +12 were common at one point, but by no means the only needed rail values. So of course there would be a variable option added to fill in gaps. Given that, designs happened. Now there's a need to support older designs still being made. Beyond that, there's still some need for values other than those you listed. We have many other battery chemistry choices these days and that will continue to evolve. I'd be worried more if there were no such options in the market.

Comment: They offer the advantage that you only need to stock one active component and use that for many designs requiring different voltages. It offers the disadvantage that external components are required to define the output voltage. The latter can a feature though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a lot of circuits but not all of them are digital, many are analog, RF etc and these do not always run at the digital voltages. Some such as ECL may be operated at a -5.2 volts. Some radio front ends require 10V. Some industrial controls like 24V. So I am glad they are available.

Comment: There are analog circuits requiring bipolar voltages of +- 12 or +- 15 V.

Answer (score 2):

What if you need 3.0 V? What if you need 20 V? What if you need 4.5 V? Fixed regulators get you the common voltages, but adjustable ones let you get whatever voltage you need.

Sure, you might not need it often, but occasionally you need something outside of the usual set of voltages for some special application.

---

Even sticking to the standard values, what if you need to be able to switch voltages on the fly, for instance to communicate with both 3.3 V and 5 V peripherals that the user might plug in? Many adjustable regulators can do that if you switch in different feedback resistors.

Comment: A programmable voltage regulator helps reduce inventory.  One part does all jobs.  A ua7815 and 7808 are hard to find.

Comment: @ronsimpson Sure, the uA7815 is hard to find--I don't think anyone still manufactures parts with the uA prefix. But exact equivalents are very easy to find--Avnet currently has almost 800,000 MC7815s in stock, and over 400,000 MC7808s.

Comment: It goes both ways. Sometimes more variable LDOs are in stock than fixed regulators, and vice versa. If board space allows, leave footprints for both kinds to maximize inventory utilization.

Comment: Why bring LDOs into the mix? The question relates to fixed or variable regulators regardless of whether they are ‘Low Drop Out’.  The 78xx series are not LDOs nor is the old skool LM317 adjustable reg.

Comment: @Kartman "LDO" is kind of just a synonym for "linear regulator" these days. The distinction seems to be disappearing.

Comment: @Hearth - last week an interviewee referred to a 7805 as a ‘LDO’.  How does one make the distinction then? If I want an LDO, do I ask for a LDO LDO?  For a 78xx, a not so LDO LDO?  These are rhetorical questions.

Comment: ok, lets assume that we are going to use a voltage regulator to generate one of many voltages like 5.0, 3.3, 2.5, 1.8V. Another system will be used to control the behaviour of this voltage regulator so it can output the required voltage. I think we use resistors to control the output voltage of the regulator. Resistors have fixed value. So now, how would we choose a resistor that can be changed dynamically and work with the voltage regulator to change its output?

Comment: @quantum231 Multiple resistors, switch different ones in or out using MOSFETs. If you want fine control over the voltage, you can use a digital potentiometer (provided the voltage range is suitable) which is essentially just that in a convenient package.

Answer (score 1):

It is just how it is with scale of economy. Since you need adjustable regulators anyway for any non-common value that is not available as a fixed voltage, most likely it makes sense to manufacture one single version of a component that is adjustable than to manufacture multiple versions of the same component with different fixed voltages. It is more difficult to predict which regulators will be popular and then manufacture them, and get left with shelves filled with the regulators that nobody will buy.

Since asked where would you use adjustable regulators, well, in power supplies for ICs. For example, I've used a chip that used maybe a 1.00V to 1.05V core voltage supply. It used a lot of other but more standard supply voltages as well. However one of the supplies needed to be very stable as it powered very sensitive circuits inside the chip, so the standard 1.2V was powred with a linear low drop-out regulator, but that LDO was powered by a switch mode regulator of about 1.4V

You simply can't live without adjustable regulators even if you power digital ICs. Or you can but only with very simple circuits with very simple supply requirements and very simple power source. In the end, digital ICs are made from analog circuits, and high speed digital communications require analog front-ends for the physical wires (e.g. Gigabit Ethernet, or USB).

Comment: Could you give some examples of where we would need a variable regulator other than the scenario where a single regulator will generate one of 5.0, 3.3, 2.5, 1.8V depending on the scenario? I can only think in terms of digital ICs since those are the only ones that I have experience with.

Comment: @quantum231 It's very common to want 15, 18, or 20 V for driving silicon carbide FETs. 15 V linear regulators exist, but I'm not sure you can get 18 or 20 V fixed voltage ones. Though for that application you're more likely using a switching regulator anyway.

Comment: @quantum231 Even silicon FETs usually use higher gate drive voltages than 5 V, outside of logic-level FETs (which have some disadvantages, so you wouldn't want to always use those).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a shocking concept, and I don't mean to trigger you.  But - there are other kinds of electronic components and circuit besides those using digital ICs.

Comment: And there are different kinds of digital ICs. And in the end, even digital ICs are made of analog components.

Comment: I don't know, that is why I am asking questions here. I only really know about ICs that are purely or partially digital. So, I am not sure what analogue ICs are out there that might need to be run using a variable voltage regulator.